# Format number with PHP

Tags: php, formatting, numbers, number-formatting

I would like to format a number with PHP, but I do not get the desired result.

The number looks like this: 2.37405 and should be shaped so that it looks like this: 2.374,05.

My code looks like this:

```
echo number_format($new_price_formatted_no_discount - ($new_price_formatted_no_discount * 5 / 100), 2); ?>
```

The output is here: 2.37 which is unfortunately wrong..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried [money_format()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)?

Comment: What's the original number?

Comment: @apokryfos The original number is 2.37405

Comment: I don't get how 2.374,05 relates to this . I would read 2.374,05 as two thousand three hundred and seventy four point zero five but the original number is around two.

Comment: show how you manipulate your numbers, and show all of it. `2.37405` looks like a string to me because  of the **dot**. Right now, we can't tell if this dot is a thousand separator or a decimal separator and that changes everything.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 2.374 is between 2 and 3, and not between 2000 and 3000.
`number_format($number, $decimals)` will first add commata for the thousands, e.g. turning 1000 into 1,000 and then round to `$decimals` decimals.
So your number 2.374 is rounded to 2.37.
You probably want 237405 to be formatted to 2,374.05

The English number format is to put commata between thousands and a dot before significant figures, whereas the Germans for example do it the other way around. Maybe you mixed up those formats?